# one common http handler instead of several

Tags: go, mux

Is it possible to not copy paste expression `commonHanlder(handler1)`, `commonHanlder(handler2)` ... `commonHanlder(handlerN)` in this code:

```
rtr.HandleFunc("/", commonHanlder(handler1)).Methods("GET")
rtr.HandleFunc("/page2", commonHanlder(handler2)).Methods("GET")
```

and set it in one place like

```
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", commonHanlder(http.DefaultServeMux))
```

But this variant is not working and gives two errors on compile:

```
./goRelicAndMux.go:20: cannot use http.DefaultServeMux (type *http.ServeMux) as type gorelic.tHTTPHandlerFunc in argument to commonHanlder
./goRelicAndMux.go:20: cannot use commonHanlder(http.DefaultServeMux) (type gorelic.tHTTPHandlerFunc) as type http.Handler in argument to http.ListenAndServe:
    gorelic.tHTTPHandlerFunc does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)
```

The full code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    initNewRelic()
    rtr := mux.NewRouter()
    var commonHanlder = agent.WrapHTTPHandlerFunc

    rtr.HandleFunc("/", commonHanlder(handler1)).Methods("GET")
    rtr.HandleFunc("/page2", commonHanlder(handler2)).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", rtr)
    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", http.DefaultServeMux)
}

func handler1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("mainPage"))
}

func handler2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("page 2"))
}

var agent *gorelic.Agent

func initNewRelic() {
    agent = gorelic.NewAgent()
    agent.Verbose = true
    agent.NewrelicName = "test"
    agent.NewrelicLicense = "new relic key"
    agent.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to call commonHandler on the root of your application and have it work for all. Since you are using mux, just wrap the mux router once.

```
func main() {
    initNewRelic()
    rtr := mux.NewRouter()
    var commonHandler = agent.WrapHTTPHandler

    rtr.HandleFunc("/", handler1).Methods("GET")
    rtr.HandleFunc("/page2", handler2).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", commonHandler(rtr))
    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

I also removed the http.DefaultServeMux reference in ListenAndServe since passing nil will automatically use the default.

Comment: `http.Handle("/", commonHanlder(rtr))` gives error `cannot use rtr (type *mux.Router) as type gorelic.tHTTPHandlerFunc in argument to commonHanlder
command
`

Comment: Ah, yes. I overlooked that. Since rtr is not a function, but an http.Handler, you need to use agent.WrapHTTPHandler not agent.WrapHTTPHandlerFunc